# Simple geometry problem on distribution of points in a plane

Tags: discrete-geometry

Consider 6 distinct points in a plane. Let $m$ and $M$ be the minimum and maximum distances between any pair of points. Show that $M/m \ge \sqrt3$.

I am more interested in arrangement of these points where the equality holds.

I figured out that the least possible value of $M/m$ should happen when the  six points lie on corners and centre of a regular pentagon. But this gave me $2cos18 = \sqrt3.6$. How do I get $\sqrt3$?

Just a hint will suffice. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am somehow feeling that my construction gives the least value of $M/m$. I am beginning to doubt the validity of the $\sqrt3$ bound (but the source is reliable).

Comment: http://www2.stetson.edu/~efriedma/maxmin/ suggests you have the correct construction. The bound follows, though it's not saturated. There's likely a simpler argument giving your bound.

Comment: Guess I was correct. Thanks.

Comment: Wenn you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets that as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats it accordingly. To get the appropriate font and spacing, you can use predefined commands like `\cos`, or, if you need an operator name for which there isn't a predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`. Also note that you need to group expressions like $3.6$ using braces (`{}`) to use them as the parameter of a command like `\sqrt`. Also, presumably you mean $2\cos18^\circ$, not $2\cos18$, and this is $\approx\sqrt{3.6}$, not $=\sqrt{3.6}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community wiki answer so the question can be marked as answered: Apparently $2\cos\pi/10$ is indeed the minimal value of the ratio.