# $M/m\ge\sqrt{3}$.

Tags: geometry

Suppose there are six distinct points in the plane. Let $m$ and $M$ be the minimum and maximum distances among the al possible distances between pairs of points. I have to show $M/m\ge\sqrt{3}$.

I have tried placing the points on the plane in an extremal fashion, but couldn't figure out how to derive such inequality.

Comment: Also related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/379082/simple-geometry-problem-on-distribution-of-points-in-a-plane.